# ifft of a gaussian function in matlab

Tags: matlab, fft, ifft

I have analytically calculated the FFT of a Gaussian function (with zero mean). Now I want to take numerical IFFT of that using MATLAB codes. Since I am new in MATLAB, I need help in doing this.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for `ifft` function in [MATLAB](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ifft.html).

Comment: Not exactly, I know what are the commands I need to use but I don't know how to plug them in to get the desired results.